# I have json object in constructor in my component and how to use the object when using click function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

***I have given below is my object in constructor.***

> I am passing value from previous conmponent to below component. and i
>   am getting the item json object. but i need to use below object when i
>   am clicking.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
     this.item= navParams.get('item');
```

}

> How i will use the item json object when i am click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use it as

```
<button (click)="myFunc()"></button>
```

and you can use it in typescript as,

```
myFunc(){
  console.log(this.item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i know the clicking function, but how to get constructor object in component. can u help me

Comment: what do you mean? you already have the item in the component.ts , its just a matter of using it

Comment: sure Sajeetharan

Comment: Sure Sajeetharan

Comment: I have small doubt In angular can i ask

Comment: ,@vaibhav. I am using json object in all components. Is there any global declaration and reuse json object in angular.  Otherwise while loading same object we will load  in all components?

Comment: @RamuMothukuri consider using a service

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<button (click)="itemUse()"></button>
```

in your html

and

```
  item;  //if not defined yet
    itemUse(){
      console.log(this.item)
}
```

in your component

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, shall i get constructor value ( this.item) inside itemUse() function.

Comment: Yes, for sure in this case

Comment: Ok i will check and i will tell you

Comment: I have small doubt In angular can i ask

Comment: and above answer is copy of mine but you marked that as an answer.

Comment: Dont mistaken me.

Comment: 1@vaibhavmaster i posted the answer before you posted and you say its a copy of yours!crazy

Comment: @Sajeetharan but first time your answer was incomplete and then you edited and copied it :).

Comment: @vaibhavmaster i did not copy your answer, just check the messages. even my first answer is right. Because op has not provided clear information